# echo within an echo statement

Tags: php, echo

I have an echo statement which gives off a variable to display a custom background image.

`<?php echo $boardDetails->bgimageurl; ?>`

However, I want to change it so that only users over a certain amount of privilege can use this feature. So I made this echo:

`<?php if($res >=25 && $res <=100 ) 
{ echo ""; } ?>`

As you can see. I need the first echo to go within the second. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've edited. and now my answer is the same as the other guy

```
<?php if($res >=25 && $res <=100 ) { echo $boardDetails->bgimageurl; } ?>
```

Comment: Not block, allow people between 25-100.

Comment: ok.  I couldn't figure why you were echoing ""

Comment: The amended code worked. Thanks.

Comment: great.  you really should also mark aynber's answer correct since it is the same and was actually first.

Answer (score 3):

Just pop it in there:

```
<?php if($res >=25 && $res <=100 ) { echo $boardDetails->bgimageurl; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will echo based on the inline if syntax or nothing if it doesn't meet the criteria:

```
<?php echo ($res >=25 && $res <=100  ? $boardDetails->bgimageurl : "")  ?>
```

If I misunderstood which action should be the result of the true the other possibility is:

```
<?php echo ($res >=25 && $res <=100  ? "" : $boardDetails->bgimageurl )  ?>
```

Comment: What would be the point in echoing an empty string?

Comment: I am presuming that the code (not shown) is something like src=' <?php echo ...?>'. Echoing an empty string instead of the url will simply disable the 'feature'. Whether we echo an empty string or nothing, the result is the same.